KitchenAid Oven (Model KDRP407HSS13) - Oven Part Lost Power; Gas Range Still Working
I have a KitchenAid oven (model KDRP407HSS13) that's lost power to the oven part.  Last night I cooked tenderloin in last night no problem.  Later that night I went to clean up and noticed that the oven digital display was out, this usually will show the time if not baking.  It looks like the oven part has lost power.  The gas range will click and light no issues.  I turned the breaker on and off (it wasn't tripped) and this didn't fix it (I didn't think it would).
I've found the manual online here but it offers no help for troubleshooting this issue.
The oven came with the house and I think it's ~20 years old.  I've had no issues with the oven until now.
Thoughts?

Do you have a voltage tester?  If so, can you pull the oven out and see if the oven plug even has power to it?  The gas line should have enough flex in it to let you pull the oven out and get access behind it to check the outlet for power.  A non-contact voltage tester would probably be sufficient in this case to see if the issue is before the oven (i.e. no power at the outlet), or within the oven itself (power is at the outlet).  You can also make sure the plug is completely plugged into the outlet as well.

@Milwrdfan The gas range will click means it has power.

These types of ovens typically have a couple of critical safety features to avoid thermal overload. Basically, when the outside of the oven cavity gets hotter than it is supposed to, a fuse that is sensitive to the ambient temperature, rather than to the amount of current, will melt in order to cut off power to the oven. That typically means, as has happened to me and appears to be your situation, that the oven is functioning just fine but due to problems with insulation or holes in the oven or whatever, too much heat is getting out of the oven. This can also happen during or shortly after a self-cleaning cycle or, of course, if there is an actual fire inside the oven. In all cases, replacing a fuse is much better than replacing your entire kitchen, or even your entire house.
The problem is that the very nature of these fuses places them in areas that are hard to get to. With my Kitchenaid double-oven I have had this with a fuse above the control panel (easy to get to) and with a fuse behind the oven (very hard to get to - had to build a contraption so that I could (with help) slide out the oven, replace the fuse (trivially easy) and then slide the oven back in (not easy at all)).
For your particular model, I have found one thermal fuse. The problems are:

It is in the very back of the oven, so it will be a bit of work to get to it.
It is relatively expensive - $100 or more from the major web appliance parts stores. A little less, but not hugely less, for compatible replacements on Amazon.
There is the possibility that the problem is elsewhere. I don't remember how I figured it out, but I correctly diagnosed which thermal fuse was the problem each time that I had the problem. But even if I could tell you how I did that, you have a very different appliance (dual-fuel oven/stove vs. electric double wall oven) so the differential diagnosis process, if applicable, will be different.

Depending on time constraints, you can either order the thermal fuse and hope it is the right thing or take apart the oven to remove the existing thermal fuse and if it has failed (easy to check with a multimeter) then order a replacement. (And if it has not failed, try to figure out what else could have gone wrong.)

I like this answer.  Additional context, the oven was baking at 400 degrees and I was boiling a stock pot for corn (burner on high) and was using another burner for bacon and brussel sprouts, so I was producing a lot of heat in the area.  I was running the hood vent as well (maybe that takes away some heat from the area?).
So maybe between the age of the thermal fuse and the heat that I was producing in the area tripped the thermal fuse.  I'd believe this.

Looking at the exploded diagram, I understand that the thermal fuse lives on the BACK of the oven.  I pull the oven out, take the thermal fuse off and check to see if it's blown?  If blown, order and replace.

Correct. Easier with some models than others

Thanks for confirming - I appreciate your help on this!  I've got to borrow a multimeter, but once I have an update I'll post.  Thank you again!
